# Accessing POST data

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm very new to PHP but have a good understanding of C,

When I want to access some post data on an API i'm creating in PHP I use:

```
 $_POST['date_set']
```

to fetch a value being passed for date - This all works perfectly, however I read I should be fetching it like this:

```
$date_set = trim(urldecode($_POST['date_set']));
```

This always returns a 00:00:00 value for the date after it's stored in my DB.

When I access directly using **$_POST['date_set']** I get whatever value was posted, for example: 2013-08-28 10:31:03

Can someone tell me what I'm messing up?

Comment: no need to use `urldecode` because PHP will do it automatically for $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE

Comment: _This always returns a 00:00:00 value for the date after it's stored in my DB._ - Your problem is likely in the code that stores and retrieves this date value to/from the database. That code isn't shown here, so we probably can't help you.

Comment: use strtodate strtotime before saving in data, the db expects the date string in some other format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only run `urldecode` over data is URL encoded. PHP will have decoded it before populating `$_POST`, so you certainly shouldn't be using that. (You might have to if you are dealing with double-encoded data, but the right solution there should be to not double encode the data).

`trim` removes leading and trailing white-space. It is useful if you have a free form input in which rogue spaces might be typed. You will need to do further sanity checking afterwards.

Comment: dont you think it can be the problem of the datatype/format of date column in db and the format of string he might be saving ?

Comment: @Deepanshu — The question says that it "all works perfectly" until he does the nonsense things that someone (wrongly) told him he should do. So no.

Answer (score 2):

You should try it like,

```
$date_set = $_POST['date_set'].explode(' ');//('2013-08-28 10:31:03').explode(' ')
echo $date_set[1];
```

or

```
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime($_POST['date_set'])));
//echo date('H:i:s',strtotime('2013-08-28 10:31:03'));
```

If you are **very new in php** the Read [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
urldecode — Decodes URL-encoded string

Description 
string urldecode ( string $str )
Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.
```

urldecode: is used only for GET requests. you should be fine using $_POST['date_set'] only.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 1):

You'd better do this way

```
if(isset($_POST['date_set'])){
 $date_set = $_POST['date_set'];
}
```

then you can use $date_set how you want.
If you still get 00:00:00 for $date_set, the problem is coming from the code which provide you the $_POST value.